# Android SQLite query result on ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Just started learning how to program for Android and now I am stuck at some doubts.

I have one SQLite db with more than one table and each table with some fields.

I've created a class to manage my database and imagine that one of the functions is something like this:

```
public Cursor getGroupData() {
    String[] values = new String[] {_ROWID, _NAME, _AGE, _PHONE};
    Cursor c = db.query(BD_TABLE, values, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
```

Now I have one of two situations.

**FIRST SITUATION**

Want to show, for example, all the names returned on my query in a ListView. With that, the user can click on a name and a new activity will show (imagine a layout with all the user information)

**SECOND SITUATION**

Want to show, for example, all the names returned on my query in a ListView. With that, the user can click on a name and a new query will be performed (Imagine get other data from that user). The query will result in returning various data and I, again, want to show some field in a ListView (for example the address). Now, if the user clicks on on of the address, a new activity will show up (for example a layout with some information about the address).

In both situation, although I'm just picking a name or an address, all the data returned by the SQLite must be available, for example, on the first situation, I pick a name, it will show on a layout, something like a contact information, but the results from the query, age and phone, must also be available.

For now I'm doing something like:

```
Cursor values = db.getGroupData();
// Now I'm thinking in putting some code to iterate over the cursor and put what I want to display on my listview on a string array

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values_I_what_to_show);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem with this is that I'm putting the data on a string array but will need all the data returned by the query.

Can you point me In some direction?

Regards,

Comment: i will suggest using [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: Isn't that deprecated? Tried to understand CursorLoader but wasn't capable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Cursor cursor =db.getGroupData();
 ArrayList<MyData> listData = new ArrayList<MyData>();
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        MyData temp = new MyData();
        temp.id = cursor.getInt(0);
        temp.name = cursor.getString(1);
        temp.age= cursor.getInt(2);
        temp.phone= cursor.getInt(3);
        listData .add(temp);
                    temp =null;
    }
cursor.close();
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, listData); //use custom adapter
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Declare MyData class :

```
  private class MyData{
   int id ;
   String name;
   int age;
   int phone;
 }
```

MyAdapter class :

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<projData> {
    private ArrayList<MyData> items;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<MyData> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
      }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
    //here getview code as per ur req 
        }
    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can't understand what is MyAdapter. Where is it defined?

Comment: Thanks. Managed some other way but will be useful in the future